# Составить регулярное выражение с помощью re

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярное выражение с помощью re python3.

**Исходные данные:**

```
"isAutoOpen": false
"stayOnPage": true,
"vacancyId": "36627904",
"employerId": "1160188",
"isWithoutTest": true,
"ignoreResponseCheck": true,
```

Мне необходимо циклом забирать значения ключа `vacancyId`, то есть `36627904`.
Поэтому шаблон должен быть универсальным.

Comment: Эта структура очень похожа на `JSON`. Может, это и есть `JSON`? Если так, то есть куда более элегантные решения.

Comment: @nomnoms12 спасибо за пример

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регулярное выражение: `"vacancyId": "(\d+)"`.

***Пример:***

```py
import re


def main():
    s = '"isAutoOpen": false "stayOnPage": true, "vacancyId": "36627904", "employerId": "1160188", "isWithoutTest": true, "ignoreResponseCheck": true,'
    r = re.findall(r'"vacancyId": "(\d+)"', s)

    for x in r:
        print(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
36627904
```

Answer (score 1):

Исходные данные можно превратить в валидный `JSON`, если:

- Добавить фигурные скобки
- Добавить запятую после значения ключа `isAutoOpen`
- Убрать завершающую запятую

Тогда можно будет использовать модуль `json` для парсинга.

***Пример:***

```py
import json


def main():
    s = '{"isAutoOpen": false, "stayOnPage": true, "vacancyId": "36627904", "employerId": "1160188", "isWithoutTest": true, "ignoreResponseCheck": true}'
    d = json.loads(s)
    print(d['vacancyId'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
36627904
```